# Recalculate Standard Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, means, variance

I know how to calculate a standard deviation when given a set of values. You must calculate the mean, then square the difference of each value between the mean to get the variance. Lastly, the standard deviation is the square root of the variance. However, I have a problem where I am given the following values:

```
Mean: 3.8 L
Standard Deviation: 1.0
```

Then I am then given a new value of 4.0L. I know that the standard deviation does not increase, because in order for it to increase the new value must be larger than the (`Mean + Standard Deviation`). I want to know how to recalculate the standard deviation for future use. Any help and explanation would be great!

Comment: In general, adding a different value will change the mean and the variance. I don't understand how you concluded that adding the above value won't affect the variance?

Comment: @copper.hat I must have worded the question wrong. I meant that I know the standard deviation won't increase, but I want to recalculate to see if the standard deviation decrease or stays the same. I don't have the variance, because I don't have any of the original values.

Comment: Do you know how many samples you have?

Comment: @copper.hat No all that was given was the mean, standard deviation, and a new value to input.

Comment: If the mean has changed how do you know the standard deviation hasn't?

Comment: Then you can't do it. If there were a huge number of samples, one more would have little impact where as if there were just two samples, the impact would be more significant.

Comment: @Karl I don't know how much the mean has changed since I do not know how many values were used in the original calculations of the mean.

Comment: @copper.hat so essentially there is not enough data given to calculate the new standard deviation?

Comment: Sorry I'd misread the new mean to be 4 not a new value.

Comment: Correct. If you knew the number of samples you could compute $\sum_k x_k $ and $\sum_k x_k^2$, but without that you are missing some constraint...

Comment: @copper.hat Okay thank you for your help! The question is asking if the standard deviation would increase, decrease or stay the same, but since I can't calculate it I'll have to make 50/50 guess of whether it will decrease or stay the same. Thanks for the help again!